# .NET Console windows

Tags: c#, .net, console

Is there any class or how to draw windows in console application using pseudo symbols like in far manager or turbo pascal?

I have found some symbols using conversion from Int to Char.

Comment: Note that C# has no ability to draw windows. .NET does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) like libraries have been used for that for a long time, here's 2 curses libraries for .NET , although I don't know how well(if at all) they work on Windows

http://www.mono-project.com/MonoCurses

http://home.nedlinux.nl/~florian/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

Start the charmap.exe applet, check the "Advanced view" option (lower left).  In the "Search for:" box type "box draw" and click Search.  Click on one of the characters, the status bar at the bottom give you the code you need to use.  For example:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        for (int ix = 0; ix < Console.WindowWidth - 1; ++ix)
            Console.Write('\u2500');
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Console class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) has quite a few methods that would allow to do this, such as [SetCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx), but there is nothing directly in the framework to help you do this type of symbol-based windowing.